# Dereferecing a double pointer coming into a function and then passing to another

Tags: c, pointers

I am having problems doing the following scenario. I have a function which comes as:

```
void testing(mystruct str**) {
    pthread threads[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, process, (void)&(*str));   //not really sure how to pass this here
    }
}

void * process(void *arg) {
    struct mystruct **value = arg;   //probably wrong but it compiles, then blows up some where else because its not really the value that was original passed.
}
```

I am new to C and as far as I understand this is whats its doing,

- I get a double pointer
- to pass it to the fuction I would pass it casted as void because thats what the function accepts and also with the address of the str pointer (or would it be the address of the pointer to pointer? &str ?)
  *then when obtaining it on the other side, I set it, i tried casting it to the struct but that did not go well either as such:

  `struct mystruct **value = *(mystruct *)arg;`

but i get "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"

any help understanding this would be much appreciated.

Comment: `pthread_create` needs a callback function of the form `void* start_routine (void *)`. If this somehow compiled despite that, your compiler is misbehaving.

Comment: you are right, bad copy paste, i am coding this on a vm and was having trouble just copying from there but yes, its a void *. Still same issue. Can you confirm i am passing it correctly from the last argument the pthread creation and also that i am dereferencing it correctly when it arrives on the other end? it compiles when just setting it to `struct mystruct **value = arg;` but it must not be right because the receving end of that  is complaining its not the right value (although i am NOT trying to alter it through out the process)

Comment: `(void)&(*str)` will most definitely not compile. I posted an answer.

Comment: *"I would pass it casted as void"* don't do that. It isn't required. In nearly all cases, casting pointer types in C is a flag you're doing something wrong. And it is a guarantee as much if you're new to C. A real [mcve] is honestly warranted, because although the code posted here is clearly wrong, is isn't even syntacticly correct. `mystruct str**` for example, is nonsense, as is `(void)&(*str)`.  I'm betting you want a pointer to *a* (singular) struct passed into each thread, not a pointer to pointers.

Comment: well unfortunately, it is a double pointer on the receiver end, and I am trying to pass it the same way it is coming but then again.. i am new to this so i may be all wrong as you pointed out. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to pass on the pointer as-is, since every object pointer type in C can be implicitly converted to/from `void*`. Still, it is more correct to de-reference the pointer one level. That is:

```
pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, process, *str);
```

IMPORTANT: This assumes that `str` points at a variable which will *not* go out of scope while the thread is executing! Passing on pointers to local variables to threads is a common source of bugs.

From there on, your thread callback should do something like this:

```
void * process(void *arg) {
    struct mystruct* ms = arg; 
    struct mystruct** ptr_ms = &arg;
```

However, the error "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" simply means that the struct definition isn't visible to the thread, causing the struct type to get treated as incomplete. So the issue might as well be a missing `#include`.

Comment: That compiled fine thank you, but i am still getting a response from the receiving end that says it has am invalid value and it prints the pointer value 0x0x7f12 etc.. the receiver end is a binary and all i know it accepts that value as `send_message(mystruct **str)`  so from the thread i am trying to do something like `send_message(&(*str))`  but that method returns the mentioned above. I really appreciate the help I am having problems wrapping my head around this double pointer stuff.

Comment: @DunkRuZ If it compiled cleanly, then your compiler is stuck in some "sucky mode", like GNU C or Visual Studio. The question here is _why_ you are using pointer to pointer? I can't answer that, only you can.